# Replace a character of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this: `[TITLE|prefix=a]`.

From that string, the text *`|prefix=a`* is dynamic. So it could be anything or empty. I would like to replace (in that case) `[TITLE|prefix=a]` with `[TITLE|prefix=a|suffix=z]`.

So the idea is to replace `]` from a string that starts with `[TITLE with |suffix=z]`.

For instance, if the string is `[TITLE|prefix=a]`, it should be replaced with `[TITLE|prefix=a|suffix=z]`. If it's `[TITLE]`, it should be replaced with `[TITLE|suffix=z]` and so on.

How can I do this with RegEx?

I have tried it this way but it gives an error:

```js
let str = 'Lorem ipsum [TITLE|prefix=a] dolor [sit] amet [consectetur]';

const x = 'TITLE';

const regex = new RegExp(`([${x})*]`, 'gi');
str = str.replace(regex, "$1|suffix=z]");

console.log(str);
```

I have also tried to escape the characters [ and ] with `` new RegExp(`(\[${x})*\]`, 'gi'); `` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remember to use `\\` in a regular string literal to define a single literal backslash.

Then, you need a pattern like

```
/(\[TITLE(?:\|[^\][]*)?)]/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O33DAU/1). Details:

- `(\[TITLE\|[^\][]*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\[TITLE` - `[TITLE` text
  - `(?:\|[^\][]*)?` - an optional occurrence of a `|` char followed with 0 or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]` - a `]` char.

Inside your JavaScript code, use the following to define the dynamic pattern:

```
const regex = new RegExp(`(\\[${x}\\|[^\\][]*)]`, 'gi');
```

See JS demo:

```js
let str = 'Lorem ipsum [TITLE|prefix=a] dolor [sit] amet [consectetur] [TITLE]';
const x = 'TITLE';
const regex = new RegExp(`(\\[${x}(?:\\|[^\\][]*)?)]`, 'gi');
str = str.replace(regex, "$1|suffix=z]");
console.log(str);
// => Lorem ipsum [TITLE|prefix=a|suffix=z] dolor [sit] amet [consectetur]
```

Comment: It works great but not if the string is `[TITLE]` only.

Comment: @Proseller Fixed by making `|` and the chars other than `[` and `]` optional.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your problem would look similar to this:

```
let str = 'Lorem ipsum [TITLE|prefix=a] dolor [sit] amet [consectetur]';

str = str.replace(/(\[[^\|\]]+)(\|[^\]]*)?\]/g, "$1$2|suffix=z]");

console.log(str);
```

Comment: That works great, thank you. But please give me some more details about the regex that you have used.

Comment: It does not take into account the dynamic nature of the regex you need to build.

Comment: The regex is actually searching for an `[` after that it collects everything that is neither `|` nor `]` and saves all this in the first group (recognizable by the braces and usable via $1 in the return). After that it collects the second group, which is optional (see the `?`). In the second group ($2) it collects a pipe `|` and then everything except of a `]`. And finally it requires a closing `]`. Unfortunately all the escapes make it hard to read. but you can see a graphical visualization at https://www.debuggex.com/r/kHCJHn6BOxRnKG_F